# memory leak with String in JDK 7

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks, jvm, stringbuilder

Can the following code possibly leak memory in JDK 7?

```
//size of input obj is around 15K
public save(List<DBObj> objs){

   //added in new EDIT

   if(objs ==null || objs.size == 0)
        return;
     if(objs.size()> 999) {
      save(objs.sublist(0,999));
      save(objs.sublist(999,objs.size())
    }  
 //EDIT finish
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 sb.append(SOMEINSERTQUERYPREFIX)

 for(DBObj obj : objs){
           //add some prefix
            sb.append(checkNULLforDBInsert(obj.getF1())).append(" , ");
            sb.append(checkNULLforDBInsert(obj.getField2())).append(" , ");
            sb.append(checkNULLforDBInsert(obj.getField3())).append(" , ");
         //app sufix
  }

}


private String checkNULLforDBInsert(String str)
    {

        if (str == null || str.toLowerCase().equals("null"))
        {

            return "null";
        } else {
            //suspecting this for leak ,Should a StringBuilder be used here too?

            return "'" + str + "'";
        }

    }
```

**Why i think its a leak**

The function checkNULLforDBInsert appends quote to every input str. Now this method will be called
for 15K * 12 number of fields in object. I think that may create a leak as a  StringBuffer must have been used for it.

Plz comment

Comment: Why on earth would that be a memory leak?

Comment: Why don't you use a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: No, it will lead to SQL injection.

Comment: This code is written by someone else .I am debugging the memory leak. @Tom .Plz forget about compilation error and lets solve the main problem

Comment: Plz donot downvote .I am thinking of a leak because 1)A quote is appended to string .Appeneding string in this way is bad right? And moreover the loop is executed for over 15K records

Comment: I cant give actual code. I just made a similar code which shows the situation in a easy way

Comment: The explanation why you think this code might cause a memory leak belongs to the question. Please add it there.

Comment: Maybe you can add a short explanation why you suspect a leak in this code. Sure, memory usage will increase by the usage of lots of strings, but if they are all garbage collected later on, it's just not really a leak.

Comment: @cringe Added a short discription about why i think its a leak

Comment: If this line `return "'" + str + "'";` disturbs you: the Compiler won't leave it that way. He replaces it with something simular to this: `return new StringBuilder("'").append(str).append("'").toString();`. Your code might cause a memory *peak*, but I don't see something that couldn't be garbage collected.

Comment: @Tom thanks.I just added next level of code. Can u have a look .Basically the recursive call

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a memory leak, as all allocated objects are only reachable through local variables, which will run out of scope once the method completes, which in turn makes the objects unreachable and eligible for garbage collection.

The code is dreadful for another reason: Concatenating user provided data into an SQL statement permits the user to send arbitrary commands to the database, which (depending on the priviledges of the database user and the kind of database) can be escalated to complete remote code execution and take over of the database server by an attacker.

More information: [SQL injection Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).